# Using asp.net roles in a blazor page

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to use asp.net Usermanager in a blazor server-side page in order to get the Roles of a user

to achieve that, I have to use the UserManager but if I try with [Inject] I get an error when I do services.Addxx<> in startup.cs

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore'1[Data.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager'1[Data.ApplicationDbContext]'.

Else if I try to use in the constructor I get this error:

> Error  CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'userManager' of 'InvoiceListBase.InvoiceListBase(UserManager)'

```
[CascadingParameter] Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; } 
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationDbContext> _userManager;
public IList<String> Roles { get; set; }

public InvoiceListBase(UserManager<ApplicationDbContext> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authstate = await AuthenticationStateTask;
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(authstate.User);
    Roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
UserManager<ApplicationDbContext>
```

To

```
UserManager<IdentityUser>
```

If your using `ApplicationUser`

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser>
```

Also to use roles you have to use `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```